# Avoiding busy waiting in this situation

Tags: c, multithreading, libcurl, apr

I have a process that uses different threads for making different type of jobs.

One such thread must send push notifications in a non-blocking way (so I will use libcurl because of the multi interface and SSL support). The master thread must pass the job to the worker and I thought about using apache apr message queue for message passing. Because in the same thread I must check for incoming messages and for the availability of the curl handles I think that I will use something like this:

```
while (1)
{
    while (apr_queue_try_pop(queue, &msg) == APR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // do something with the message
    }

    // perform a select or poll in the curl multi handle
    // treat the handles that are available for reads/writes
}
```

in the thread start function.

This is kind of busy waiting, is there a better solution?

Using C99 and Linux x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer your question precisely, there is just not enough information.  But, if the code you are showing is the worker code, i.e. launched in a thread, and the need to push notices is frequent, then I do not see a reason this would not work.  As for your question *This is kind of busy waiting, is there a better solution?* I usually do something to cause the thread to be idle once the task it is responsible to do is finished, such as use a sleep(1000).  The remainder of the thread time slice is not used looping.  Like this:

```
while (1)
{
    while (apr_queue_try_pop(queue, &msg) == APR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // do something with the message
    }

    // perform a select or poll in the curl multi handle
    // treat the handles that are available for reads/writes
    Sleep(1000);
}
```